# Functional integral

Tags: integration, mathematical-physics

In the path integral formula 
$$\psi(x,t)=\frac{1}{Z}\int_{{\bf x}(0)=x}\mathcal{D}{\bf x}e^{iS[{\bf x},\dot{\bf x}]}\psi_0({\bf x}(t))$$
$\mathcal{D}{\bf x}$ denotes integration over all paths with ${\bf x}(0)=x$ and the integral is called a functional integral. I tried to find a definition of a functional integral and found the wikipedia article (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_integration) not helpful at all. Can someone please give me a clear and concise definition of a functional integral?
 Many thanks in advance!

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/19495/mathematics-of-path-integral-state-of-the-art

Comment: Check the DETAILS section in the following: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/384919/83405 There you will find a fairly complete discussion of all basic facts and calculations of path integrals in the simplest case of a free non-relativistic particle. Attention is given to detail, the measure, normalisation, relation to Schrodinger eqn, Wick rotation, determinants and their evaluation. The exposition there is the standard approach that one follows for essentially all path integral calculations and when interactions are included, and generalises readily to field theory as well.

Comment: @Wakabaloola Thanks a lot! The problem is that it is not clear at all why $D \tilde {x}=\prod_{n\neq 0}\frac{da_n}{K}$ defines a "measure" since there are a lot of measure theoretic problems involved when it goes to infinite dimensional spaces nor is it clear what might be ment by $\dot{\bf x}$ if the path isn´t differentiable. May be I find some answers in Johnsons and Lapidus book

Comment: I doubt you will find an answer if you want to be too mathematically precise, after all the measure is ambiguous but the magic lies in the fact that the ambiguity doesn’t affect observables if the theory is renormalisable. There is the so called principle of ultra locality of Polchinski that states that any ambiguity can be absorbed into a local counterterm in the action (but there are cases where this fails).

Comment: Incidentally, the measure definition you just quoted is very natural within perturbation theory given that for that measure one essentially Fourier expands the path integral fields subject to boundary conditions and then every field configuration is completely specified by the list of numbers $\{a_n\}$, so integrating over those is equivalent to integrating all fields.

Comment: A more mathematically "pleasing" definition might be to define it via the natural inner product as explained (if only briefly) in the link I sent you

Comment: One more comment: You never need to worry about whether the paths are differentiable, given that the continuous "time" parameter is already integrated out in that approach by the inner product in the action. I'll leave it at that for now.

Comment: Many thanks! I´ll have to think about it !